# How can I monitor the quality of my .NET code?

Tags: test-coverage, code-climate

I am currently developing a Ruby project and I often use code climate to see the quality of my code. The thing is, we will rewrite the code in .NET, so my boss wants to be able to monitor the quality of code by uploading the code into tool just like in codeclimate.

Do you guys know any tool alternative (free or not) to code climate for .NET?

Comment: By asking for an off-site resource your question is probably [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It's probably worth your while searching on Google for some .NET code analysis tools and *trying* some - many of them have evaluation periods, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not that familiar with code climate. However there are few tools in .net arena which an do the same. You can use Visual Studio Static Analysis tool for code analysis. And also you can use [nCover](https://www.ncover.com/products) product as well. There is one more product called DotTrace from Jetbrains which is also a nice product in my opinion. And with Visual Studio 2015 you will receive more reading on memory usage during code execution etc. You may want to look at those features as well.

Comment: things you have mentioned match with my thoughts, I made a search and found the same things. ncover and dotCover from jetbrains also are most popular ones I guess, thanks for you comment @qamar it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

It is very recent that I have started using [SonarCube](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hkamel/archive/2013/10/24/visual-studio-2013-static-code-analysis-in-depth-what-when-and-how.aspx) for monitoring quality of our application, and I must say that it is a very good tool with tons of features with support for variety of languages.

You can view the code quality with [Visual Studio Code Analysis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hkamel/archive/2013/10/24/visual-studio-2013-static-code-analysis-in-depth-what-when-and-how.aspx) and [Code Metrics](http://blog.pluralsight.com/identify-code-smells) also, but I think SonarCube is closer to Code Climate.

Comment: thanks, I will have a look on SonarCube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com), a pretty cool tool completely integrated to Visual Studio, it integrates a wide range of features.